# Setting up database connection alarm using Terraform with database connection formula

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to setup the Cloudwatch alarm for database connections in Terraform.

```
`resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "db_connections" {
  alarm_name          = "db_connections"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "DatabaseConnections"
  namespace           = "AWS/RDS"
  period              = "300"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = var.db_connection_threshold
  alarm_description   = "Db connections"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]
 

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = "${var.db_instance_id}"
  }
}
`
```

What i am trying to achieve is to setup using this formula GREATEST({log(DBInstanceClassMemory/805306368,2)*45},{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/8187281408,2)*1000}). If it is greater than 90 percent then the Alarm rises.
Is there any possibility for that in Terraform. I tried with giving var threshold =formula/100 and it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You would probalby need to use `metric_query` option and add one for the first and second part of the equation. More info here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm#metric_query and here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html#metric-math-syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you must use that formula to create the DB connections alarm and what database engine you use, however, here is how I managed to calculate the maximum connections for my databases and create the alarm.

I calculated the maximum DB connections knowing the instance's memory and using the formula from the page [Maximum number of database connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections). For instance, for MySQL:

> {DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}

To find the `DBInstanceClassMemory`, you must convert the instance's memory from GiB (Gibibytes) to Bytes.

> 1 GiB = 1073741824 bytes

The instance classes' memory amount in GiB can be found on the page [Hardware specifications for DB instance classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Summary). So, the maximum number of connections for `db.t3.small` (MySQL) is:

> (2 * 1073741824) / 12582880 ~= 170.66710

As a result, the instance can have a maximum of around **170 connections**. Knowing the number you can easily calculate the threshold for your alarm using the percentage.

My **Terraform** module looks something like this:

```
...
variable "db_instance_name" {
  type        = string
  nullable    = false
}

variable "db_instance_class" {
  type        = string
  nullable    = false
}

variable "db_connections_limit_threshold" {
  type        = number
  default     = 80
  description = "The maximum percent of connections connected to the DB instance. Default: 80"
}

locals {
  datasets = {
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Summary
    db_instance_classes_memory_gib = {
      # db.t4g – burstable-performance instance classes with AWS Graviton2 processors
      "db.t4g.2xlarge" : 32,
      "db.t4g.xlarge"  : 16,
      "db.t4g.large"   : 8,
      "db.t4g.medium"  : 4,
      "db.t4g.small"   : 2,
      "db.t4g.micro"   : 1,
      # db.t3 – burstable-performance instance classes
      "db.t3.2xlarge"  : 32,
      "db.t3.xlarge"   : 4,
      "db.t3.large"    : 8,
      "db.t3.medium"   : 4,
      "db.t3.small"    : 2,
      "db.t3.micro"    : 1,
      # db.t2 – burstable-performance instance classes
      "db.t2.2xlarge"  : 32,
      "db.t2.xlarge"   : 16,
      "db.t2.large"    : 8,
      "db.t2.medium"   : 4,
      "db.t2.small"    : 2,
      "db.t2.micro"    : 1
    }
  }
  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections
  # Max Connections: DBInstanceClassMemoryBytes/12582880
  # db.t3.micro: 1 GiB (RDS Instance RAM) = 1073741824 bytes (DBInstanceClassMemoryBytes)
  max_connections_limit = (local.datasets.db_instance_classes_memory_gib[var.db_instance_class] * 1073741824) / 12582880
  db_connections_limit_threshold = floor((local.max_connections_limit / 100) * var.db_connections_limit_threshold)
}

# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "db_connections_limit" {
  alarm_name          = "rds-${var.db_instance_name}-limitDBConnections"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "5"
  metric_name         = "DatabaseConnections"
  namespace           = "AWS/RDS"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = local.db_connections_limit_threshold
  alarm_description   = "Average database connections amount reached ${var.db_connections_limit_threshold} percent of the limit, may cause connection disruption"
  alarm_actions       = var.sns_topic_arns
  ok_actions          = var.sns_topic_arns

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = var.db_instance_name
  }
}
...
```

**NOTE!** As I could not find the source of the instance's hardware specification about memory, I hardcoded it into the local variable `datasets` as this information is less likely to be changed.